# Optimizing a query which causes deadlocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have one table-valued function that causes a lot of deadlocks. The thing is that it works with a lot of tables and goes through a lot of data. I am trying to optimize it but I am stuck and I do not know where to start.

I'd like to ask if something u would recommend to try so that I have something to start with.

Here is execution plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B12i_qpGH

[here are statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV0OI.png)

I can add some more info to deadlocks. For identifying them I am using sp_blitzLock

[Calling of table-valued function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Pqt.png)

Comment: It is actually an actual execution plan. Yes, it is a table-valued function. I added with screenshot how do I call table-valued function.

Comment: It seems that statistics might be a bit stale on several tables. But without more details this is really difficult.

Comment: I can add more details, just need to know which..

Comment: The function for sure. And probably the tables involved with that function. Do the deadlocks disappear if you remove the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the isolation level then you could avoid the locks.

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED.`

But it depends if this is appropriate in your case.

Comment: READ UNCOMMITTED has some **very serious** side effects. Things like missing and/or duplicate rows. If accuracy is at all important this is a terribly bad idea. Remember that isolation level is the same thing as putting the NOLOCK hint on every single table in every single query. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere And using this hint is dealing with the symptom instead of fixing the problem.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I was thinking about it but now I need to reconsider if this is what I want.

Comment: Or I can try to put with no lock just to some objects, which are present in deadlock

Comment: I would suggest not putting on the NOLOCK hint for tables that are deadlocking. That is dealing with the symptom instead of the problem.